# Getting json response from server

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

Please someone help me in this,
I have a `php` script which returns `Json` response as **"success"** if condition is satisfied.
I have put a log statement and I am getting response as "success" but when I put reesponse in **if statement** it does not recognize it.
plus if I get the response "success" i want to change the button color from red to green in **if statement** which is giving me error and my application crashes.
so my problem is:

1. I get the response "success" but how to put it in if statement? because it directly execute else statement.
2. The button change statement makes my application crash if i put the button change statement in else part for testing.

Here is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Login Status: " + session.isLoggedIn(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /**
     * Call this function whenever you want to check user login
     * This will redirect user to LoginActivity is he is not
     * logged in
     * */
    session.checkLogin();

    setContentView(R.layout.movie_detail);
    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonchange);
    titlee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mtitle);
    date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mdate);
like=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mlikes);
    video=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mvideo);
    idd=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mid);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    UniqueId=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
    ts=(TextSwitcher)findViewById(R.id.tsLikesCounter);



    Intent i=getIntent();
    //image.setImageResource(i.getStringExtra("THUMB"));
    titlee.setText(i.getStringExtra("TITLE"));
   like.setText("Likes = "+i.getStringExtra("LIKES"));
    date.setText("Date = " + i.getStringExtra("DATE"));
    video.setText("Video = " + i.getStringExtra("VIDEO"));
    idd.setText(i.getStringExtra("IDD"));
    UniqueId.setText(i.getStringExtra("UNIQUEID"));



   String id = idd.getText().toString();

   String unique = UniqueId.getText().toString();

    // private void insertToDatabase(String id,String unique){
    class SendPostReqAsyncTaskk extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String paramUsername = params[0];
           String paramAddress = params[1];

            String id = idd.getText().toString();
            String unique = UniqueId.getText().toString();


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unique", unique));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method

           try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MY_URL");
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

               if(json=="success"){
                   Log.d("IN IF::", json);
                   bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green1);
               }
               else {
                   Log.d("IN ELSE:::", json);

               }
               // writing response to log
               Log.d("Http Response:::", json);
              // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            HttpEntity  entity = response.getEntity();

               //JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(TAG_SUCCESS);

              //  int success =response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            return "success";


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }
    }

  SendPostReqAsyncTaskk check = new SendPostReqAsyncTaskk();
   check.execute(id, unique);

}
```

here is the error to button change statement

> 10-20 10:34:56.597    2433-2452/? D/IN ELSE:::﹕ "success"
>   10-20 10:34:56.787    2433-2452/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
>   10-20 10:34:56.797    2433-2452/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>        Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>               at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2812)
>               at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
>               at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
>               at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5139)
>               at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:7486)
>               at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7395)
>               at com.sne.movielist.MovieDetailActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTaskk.doInBackground(MovieDetailActivity.java:145)
>               at com.sne.movielist.MovieDetailActivity$1SendPostReqAsyncTaskk.doInBackground(MovieDetailActivity.java:114)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
>   10-20 10:34:56.797      175-175/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.sne.movielist/.MovieDetailActivity
>   10-20 10:34:56.887      175-192/? I/ActivityManager﹕ ensureBootCompleted():enableScreenfalse
>   10-20 10:34:56.897    2433-2433/? I/ActivityThread﹕ queueIdle
>   10-20 10:34:56.897    2433-2433/? V/ActivityThread﹕ Reporting idle of ActivityRecord{4a4c4b50 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4a4c4618 {com.sne.movielist/com.sne.movielist.MainActivity}} finished=false

Comment: write like this `json.equals("success")`

Comment: Please post your json response

Comment: my response is only one field as       "success"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: i wrote this way json.equals("success"), still not workin @satyen udeshi

Comment: check 1st line in my logcat ..i get response like that as "success"

Comment: Can you post your `json` it could be a `JSONObject` also

Comment: call this method `setBackgroundResource` in UI thread. in `postExecute()` method

Comment: ok then compare like this json.equals("\"success\"");

Comment: u mean like  json.equals("\"success"\");???/

Comment: yes, and update your button in `onPostExecute()` method

Comment: @BOss PostExecute will execute evrytime right?? but i want to change button only when i get response as "success" so where should i put it???

Comment: return "failed" when your login is failed and "success" when login succeeds from `doInBackground()` method. Then in your `postExecute()` method compare the `result` and do the UI operations

Comment: @Snehaal updated my answer see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `equals()` method to compare `Strings`,

like `json.equals("\"success\"")`

And regarding the crash , you try to update `UI` from `doInBackground()` method so it is crashing, to update the UI you should do in `onPostExecute()` method as it is guaranteed to execute in `UI` thread.

In your case you can do something like below

In your `doInBackground()` method return the `json` and compare the result in `onPostExecute()` ,

```
// private void insertToDatabase(String id,String unique){
class SendPostReqAsyncTaskk extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String paramUsername = params[0];
       String paramAddress = params[1];

        String id = idd.getText().toString();
        String unique = UniqueId.getText().toString();

        String json = "";
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unique", unique));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method

       try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("MY_URL");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return json;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result.equals("\"success\"")){
         // Update your Button here
        } else {

        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank alott @Satyen Udesh.. Both problems solved..bless you.

Comment: just a note to others: in onPostExecute in edited code posted my Satyen replace result with json.

Answer (score 2):

As for the json issue, first of all never compare strings in java using `==`, always use `equals`:

```
if (json.equals("success"))
```

Also, make sure you're comparing to the right response. It could be that instead of a simple `"success"` string, you're getting a `"{success}"` json object string (maybe in a key-value fashion). Print out the response to the log and see the exact format of the response.

As for the exception, it says it all:

```
Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
     Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

You can only update UI components on the UI thread, since that's the thread that created it.

If you're running inside an `Activity`, you can use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)), or to be on the safe side just use a `Looper`:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As other suggested you should not use **==** operator for comparing **two strings.** You should use:

```
if (json.equals("success"))
Or
if (json.equalsIgnoreCase("success"))
```

And for the crash you have to move the below code snippet to you **onPostExecute()** method like as below:

```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(json=="success"){
                   Log.d("IN IF::", json);
                   bt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green1);
            } else {
                   Log.d("IN ELSE:::", json);

            }
   }
```